# rdlc Report Footer feature

Tags: rdlc

Is there a way to implement a report footer in .rdlc. There is no such a thing out of the box, but I really need to have that report footer like feature implemented. To picture out an example, I have variable page number document (based on Tablix), then at the end on the last page after the page break I need to have some more text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone would run into similar problem, I was able to achieve that by inserting a Rectangle object, and setting up PageBreak property

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did exactly?